# Issue while execute tsql function

Tags: function, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have written the following function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetData
   (@value AS VARCHAR(MAX),
    @pattern AS VARCHAR(MAX),
    @masker AS VARCHAR,
    @notMaskedCount AS INT) 
RETURNS NCHAR(47) 
AS BEGIN
   DECLARE @nextPatIdx INT
   SET @nextPatIdx = PATINDEX('%' + @pattern + '%', @value)

   WHILE @nextPatIdx > 0 AND @nextPatIdx < LEN(@value) - @notMaskedCount
   BEGIN
        SET @value = Stuff(@value, @nextPatIdx, 1, @masker)
        SET @nextPatIdx = PATINDEX('%' + @pattern + '%', @value)
   END
   RETURN CONVERT(NCHAR(40), @value) + '_data'
END
```

Run it with :

```
select dbo.GetData('152648494','[a-zA-Z0-9]', 'x', 4)
```

If I execute it throw C# and try readdata it throws exception
If I runt it viahttp://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6ee81/1 I get an error
It doen`t complete the execution
What is wrong - the function / the way I call it?

Comment: yes it is - as you see I transfer 'x' as masker

Comment: @masker AS VARCHAR(1)

Comment: Then I'd personally use `CHAR(1)` (instead of `VARCHAR(1)`) - for just a single character, there's really no benefit in having the "variable length" property of `VARCHAR` ...

Comment: Can you show us **how** you call it from C#?

Comment: @marc_c - char(1) did help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You achieved a infinite loop as you can check using this piece of code:

```
---select dbo.GetData('152648494','[a-zA-Z0-9]', 'x', 4)
declare

@value AS VARCHAR(MAX) = '152648494',
@pattern AS VARCHAR(MAX) = '[a-zA-Z0-9]',
@masker AS VARCHAR(1) = 'x',
@notMaskedCount AS INT = 4 


DECLARE @nextPatIdx INT
SET @nextPatIdx = PATINDEX('%' + @pattern + '%', @value)

WHILE @nextPatIdx > 0 AND @nextPatIdx < LEN(@value) - @notMaskedCount
BEGIN
    SET @value = Stuff(@value, @nextPatIdx, 1, @masker)
    SET @nextPatIdx = PATINDEX('%' + @pattern + '%', @value)
    print @nextPatIdx;
END

print 'END'
select CONVERT(NCHAR(40), @value) + '_data'
```

Maybe if you change the inequality

```
@nextPatIdx > 0
```

to

```
@nextPatIdx > 1
```

It ill exit the infinite loop but I need more info to find out what you desired output

**EDIT**

I guess you need to change your loop to it.

```
WHILE @nextPatIdx > 0 AND @nextPatIdx <= LEN(@value) - @notMaskedCount
BEGIN
    SET @value = Stuff(@value, @nextPatIdx, 1, @masker)
    --SET @nextPatIdx = PATINDEX('%' + @pattern + '%', @value)      
    SET @nextPatIdx += 1

END
```

Comment: the output should be xxxxx8494

Comment: all alphanumeric ,despite last 4, are transferred to 'x'

Comment: If all you need is to obfuscate everything less the last 4 digits why are you using patindex and @pattern?

Comment: for the input 12 7   8912 the result will be xx x  8912